# How to set reusable code in AngularJS and Ionic Auth?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-factory

So I am using Ionic and the Ionic Authentication with this code:

```
.controller('newEntryCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicAuth', '$state', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicAuth, $state) {
    if ($ionicAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
    $state.go('login');
    }
}])
```

That code works and I have lots of controllers. Is there a way to just inject a factory and never do if else in my controller already?

Answer (score 1):

Write Authentication in run.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$ionicAuth', '$state',
   function ($rootScope, $ionicAuth, $state) {
       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
         if ($ionicAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            $state.go('login');
         }
      });
   }
]);
```

Comment: I think this will work though even login controller will have this so it will be on a loop.

Comment: Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application.
If you will write inside controller, it will not call until unless controller is not initialized.

Comment: I dont understand but I will try